# Dot product of two symbolic vectors

Tags: python, sympy

I'm using sympy for some calculations, I have been created two 4-vectors whitout components using MatrixSymbol like this

```
q=MatrixSymbol('q',4,1)
K=MatrixSymbol('K',4,1)
```

but, I need to declare that its scalar product is zero or any other value for next calculations.

I have been tried

```
K*q==0
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```py
from sympy import MatrixSymbol, Eq
from sympy.matrices.expressions import DotProduct

q = MatrixSymbol('q', 4, 1)
K = MatrixSymbol('K', 4, 1)

dot_product_eq = Eq(DotProduct(K, q), 0)
```

**EDIT**: the class' name is `DotProduct`, can be imported like above.

Comment: NameError: name 'Dot' is not defined

Comment: @LluisGerardo Sounds like you missed the import at the top.

Comment: No, his solution does not work

Comment: I corrected @Probedinsky's answer! Maybe he was using an older version of sympy...

Comment: for numpy arrays `*` is element wise, but `dot` for matrix.  `@` was added as a matrix multiplication operator, I'm not sure which sympy classes implement the operator or method.